# WPF application with send mail open account

Tags: c#, wpf, email, smtp

i have WPF application with send mail function.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("user_name", "password");
smtp.Credentials = basicCredential;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

i noticed that McAfee antivirus bloks the SMTP mail by default and only after modifing McAfee configuration "prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail" property to false i could send email. is there any email account that will not be blocked with any antivirus without any configuration modification (Yahoo maybe...)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I'm afraid the only way of overcoming this is by applying a rule to your AV to allow emails sent from within your application. At least this is what I have done in the past since I couldn't find any other way.

Comment: does it mean that all PCs with McAfee will block the mail?

Comment: All AVs will block your application sending mails not the mail itself but the mail through your application and this is regardless of the provider you use to send emails (Gmail, Yahoo etc.)